# modify function and If statement

Tags: php

I have a inputbox that displays a default text "Input Network ID Here...". I need to take `$inputUri` and check it against function `checkUrl($string)` to see if its still there. If the text hasn't been cleared then display the `addError` message

```
public function checkUrl($string)
{
    $inputUri = 'Input Network ID Here...';
    if(empty($string) || preg_match("#^([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_ -]*(?:.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_ -]*)+):?(d+)?/?#i", $string)) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if( isset($this) )
        {
            $this->addError("Input Network ID");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Delan i've tried if( isset($this) || $inputUri == $string ) and
if(empty($string) || preg_match("#^([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_ -]*(?:.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_ -]*)+):?(d+)?/?#i", $string) $inputUri != $string) no luck

Comment: In an object, `$this` is *always* set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the code is never entering the `else` block.

Perhaps you should change your first `if` line (line 3) to this:

```
if( (empty($string) || preg_match("#^([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_ -]*(?:.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_ -]*)+):?(d+)?/?#i", $string) && $string != $inputUri )
```